MapServer transforms the LABEL text content into date format
I have a case when the LABEL content is the text like "50-10-2". Not always, but in some situations on the map it gets interpreted as date and gets shown as "1950/10/02".
Is there the way to fix it with map file settings?
I tried to get the reply in MapServer manuals (https://mapserver.org/mapfile/index.html) but found nothing useful.
